# How can I first save the object that doesn't exist then set it in JPA ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions

In my scenario, article and tag is a ManyToMany unidirectional relationship.

**Article.class**

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ARTICLE_TAG", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID"))
    Set<Tag> tags;

    ...
}
```

And I set the ArticleDAO and the TagDAO all @ApplicationScoped, the ArticleService and TagService all @RequestScoped. In my ArticleService, I first check that if the tag already exists in the database, if so, set it directly, if not, the method **tagService.findTagByValue()** will throw a NoResultException, then I save a new tag to the database and then set it in the catch field. But the question is, I do found that the tag has been persisted (**I can see its id has been set in debug console**), but in my database, there's still no records and just one line called **getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities** get printed in the output console, no more other info. It seems not a rollback, what's wrong there? Here is my code:

**ArticleService.class**

```
@RequsetScoped
@Transactional
public class ArticleService {

        public void createArticle(ArticleDTO articleDTO) throws Exception {
            Article article = DTOUtil.map(articleDTO, Article.class);

            // check then set tags;
            Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
            tags.addAll(validateKeywords(articleDTO.getKeywords()));
            article.setTags(tags);

            ...

            articleDAO.create(article);
        }

        private Set<Tag> validateKeywords(String[] keywords) {
            Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
            if (keywords.length != 0) {
                for (String keyword : keywords) {
                    try {
                        Tag tag = tagService.findTagByValue(keyword);
                        tags.add(tag);
                    } catch (NoResultException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        Tag tag = new Tag(TagType.KEYWORD);
                        tag.setTagValue(keyword);
                        tagService.createTag(tag);
                        tags.add(tag);
                   }
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }

    ...

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you think "CMP" is?

Comment: @SteveC it stands for Container-Managed Persistence, so I don't need to call entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit() everytime. Am I right?

Comment: Lol, you mean CMT, which is Container Managed Transactions. CMP is the predecessor to JPA, and is possibly the number one contender for the reason why everyone hated the old J2EE.

Comment: @SteveC Wow, thank you! I misunderstand many important concepts...

Comment: the database just synchronized after the transaction committed successfully. by that time you wont see the DB operations done from
 outside to the living transaction.